# I can not run complete code "npm install"

Tags: npm

Environment: 
 - Linux 18.04 
 - Nodejs version 10.15.0 
 - npm version 6.4.1

When run command line `sudo npm install`, i received error:

[image]
[image]

How can I fix it now? please help me.

Comment: Please do not post error messages as a screenshot. Use formatted text and copy paste the relevant error message.

Comment: The error message also references a debug.log file at the very bottom. What is its content?

Comment: yep. I will edit my post again

Comment: I known my issue, permission for npm is missing.